# Rails 3.0.7 -> How do you get your tests to run faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, testing

I am running mysql, database_cleaner, Rspec, etc. I have about 518 tests so far and they take 88 seconds to run. This is unacceptable to me as my app development is just beginning.

So before going further, I'd like to try and find ways to reduce the time it takes to run these tests - hopefully without having to actually change the tests.

In most cases, I am trying to use stubs. However, when I am testing models and queries, I do use the database.

I think database_cleaner is slowing them down, but I don't know how to test queries and stuff without it.

Using sqlite3 with the ":memory:" option only seems to shave off about 10 seconds (kind of disappointing result...)

What can I do to really speed up my tests?

Comment: What's the split between unit/functional/integration tests in those 518?

Comment: They are all unit except for the queries tests. I'd say most of them are unit. 20-25% are integration (queries... which is kind of unit when you think of it). There is no high-level testing going on. The highest level of my tests is the controllers, which use stubbing

Comment: For those following this, the problem is factory_girl. It is super slow. 9 people found this question interesting, and I would bet as if I had pocket aces that all 9 of you use factory_girl like I am. It is responsible for .25 to .35 seconds of wasted time per test! This is unacceptable, and I am looking to either correct it... or swap it out for something else before I continue.

Comment: Well, I have changed all `Factory.build`/`Factory.create` calls to simple Ruby `MyClass.new` calls. Now 250 controller tests run in about 5 seconds instead of god knows how long. It is FAST. And I have to tell you, not using factories is not that much of a pain honestly. Just set the values you need, and if it's annoying, stub it. Problem solved. I don't know why we use Factory girl for. It is literally many orders of magnitude less efficient than simply making the instance yourself. I have no idea what the hell is going on inside of Factory.build... but it's bloated and inefficient.

Comment: Yep, I have gotten all my tests (even more now than when I first made the question) to run in 27.x seconds after either removing Factory girl when it wasn't appropriate, or calling .build() and using :default_strategy => :build whenever possible. That's a 75% speed improvement overall, and in some cases, it was a 2000% speed improvement.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the speed is using MySQL or Postgres rather than sqllite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ryan Brunner offered a lot of great advice. Everything he said is true in general, yet did not apply to me.

I didn't mention Factory Girl because I didn't think to mention it (don't ask). It turned out to be very relevant detail because it was responsible for the tests running so slow.

By simply removing Factory girl completely from my controller tests (I was using `Factory.build`), I have managed to get them down from 50 seconds to something like 5.

The reason is that `Factory.build` calls `Factory.create` for associations, which causes a database hit... so if you have a lot of associations, it will take awhile to create a new model object. But even more, that only accounted for 30-35% of the overhead in my case. Factory_girl was actually spending 65-70% of its time doing non-database stuff. I have no idea why, but after forcing every call to be `Factory.build`, it will still taking quite awhile to build my objects. Going with basic `MyClass.new` ended up being **MUCH** faster.

My entire test suite now takes a little under 30 seconds instead of up to 90 seconds. That is a 300% speed increase in general by making these changes... but when it came to the controller tests, I got a 2000% speed increase - and I was already stubbing! All of that performance overhead was due to `Factory.build`! That is where most of the gains came from.

Of course, I went back into my models and used `Factory.build` or simply `MyClass.new` wherever I could.

I also added `:default_strategy => :build` in `factories.rb` too whenever I could, to prevent Factory Girl from hitting the database. If you ask me, this should be the default as only 1 test failed as a result of this change, but I managed to get 10 entire seconds out of my model tests by this change alone.

If you're having problems like I am, follow these steps and you should notice a 2-3x speed improvement with not much drawback.

Answer (score 17):

There's a variety of strategies you can use to speed up your test times. If you're just starting, and you're seeing an 88 second run time, I would imagine a good number of these apply to you:

- **Use spork** - Spork will do all the bootstrapping and environment requires once, keep that in memory, and only reload your tests. It can be a huge help with running tests quickly.
- **Be smart about how you test** - Personally, my workflow is to develop tests, run the full test suite to see what fails, and then only run the new / failed tests until I can get those green. Finally, when I'm all done I run the suite one last time to see if I regressed something else.
- **Clean up your Gemfile** - The majority of Rails boot time is spent in requires, and if you have gems you're not using anymore, you're adding load time for no benefit. Take out anything you're not using, and consider placing things only used in one or two spots in a named group so you can require them manually during execution (be careful with this - you're trading initial load speed for request performance, which is great for dev, but crappy for production)
- **Be smart about what to stub and mock out** - If you're truly doing unit tests, for instance, you should avoid touching the database althogether, or at least for your controller tests. Think about what the responsibility of the class really is. A controller isn't responsible for saving records, it's responsible for telling the models to save records. Even models aren't responsible for saving things in databases, they're responsible for telling ActiveRecord to.
- **If you're stubbing things out well, consider not including Rails**. You'll need to have nearly all ActiveRecord functionality stubbed out in your tests, but if you can do this, you'll see a *massive* decrease in your test time (probably more than an order of magnitude).

Comment: So I should stop using Rails? I am doing everything else that you suggested ;)

Comment: @Ryan Brunner: I'm serious. I feel like because 9 people raised your post up that it's probably what the best practices answer is... so what happens if you're already doing that? :/

Comment: If you're seriously doing everything I'm talking about 100% (particularly stubbing out ActiveRecord), then you **should** be able to not include Rails in your tests without any problems. By "stop using Rails", I mean don't include it in your tests, not switch to a different framework.

Comment: Incidentally, if you only have 518 tests, and you ARE being perfect with stubs / mocks, then you are either running some very intensive code, you have a massive Gemfile, or your computer is sorely in need of upgrading. Do those 518 include Cucumber or anything with a headless browser?

Comment: @Ryan Brunner: Nope, there is no cucumber. Everything is basic RSpec. I am testing models, controllers, queries, etc. I try and have render_views turned on when I can. I have am intel quadcore machine... it can't be that slow... can it? My gemfile is also rather small. It's nothing like the rails apps I see in github. Not even close.

Comment: @Ryan Brunner: I figured out why the tests were running so slow. It is factory_girl. It not only uses `Factory.create()` to create child associations, even `Factory.build()` takes up .25 to .35 seconds per test depending on how many objects it must build. This is what is causing all of my tests to run so poorly. What do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the following hack to reduce time spent in the Garbage Collector:

http://makandra.com/notes/950-speed-up-rspec-by-deferring-garbage-collection

The article mentions a 15% improvement, but in my tests, I'm seeing around 25% with Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.x and RSpec 2.0.

Also, if you aren't using autotest, that may help, so you are only running tests for code that has changed.

Finally, try using the RSpec "--profile" option to identify the 10 slowest examples, and see if you can optimize the performance of the worst offenders; In one of my projects it turned out that just 3 of my tests doubled my test execution time for 150 tests, so I "fixed" them and it brought the entire test suite back to an acceptable time scale.

Comment: Well, I tried the deferred garbage collection and it didn't really make much different. It's 85 seconds... which could just be margin of error :/ It was worth a shot though! I'll try the profile option next

Comment: Cool! About 35% improvement for my app.

Comment: I'm jealous. This didn't do anything for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to run all of your tests all of the time? You could set up rake tasks for different sets of tests and just run the ones that are relevant to parts of the application you've changed recently. Surely most of the tests would be running on code that hasn't changed. Then every so often you can run the full set of specs just to make sure everything's compatible. That seems like the easiest solution anyway.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm currently doing as it is. Still, I can get 1800 java tests to run in 70 seconds... so there's gotta be a way to get closer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you enable use_transactional_fixtures in RSpec then you shouldn't need to use database_cleaner at all.

Also, consider using [NullDB](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb) to avoid hitting the real database, except where you have to (my approach is to never hit the database in unit tests, only in integration tests).

Comment: Well, that's the thing - I had use_transactional_fixture = true, but I got database failures anyway when I was testing queries. I had to make some "mini databases" to ensure that my queries were working correctly. Unfortunately, use_transaction_fixtures didn't work - probably because I was using Factory Girl to create the models (I didn't care much for fixtures). But once I did that, I needed database_cleaner or the tests would not pass on repeated runs of the tests

Comment: I think the point about use_transactional_fixtures and Databasecleaner might be moot anyway. I tried the tests with a clean database and databasecleaner disabled... and the tests take the same time... so I doubt this would improve my situation :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at parallel testing with `Hydra`:

http://logicalfriday.com/2011/05/18/faster-rails-tests-with-hydra/

Look here also:

http://www.adomokos.com/2011/04/running-rails-rspec-tests-without-rails.html